# Ceilometer Alarm Error - With Heat (OpenStack)

Tags: openstack, autoscaling, heat, ceilometer

i have a problem i can't image why....

i have downloaded an autoscaling heat template for openstack. In this template files are the following resources:

```
cpu_alarm_high:
    type: OS::Ceilometer::Alarm
    properties:
      description: Scale-up if the average CPU > 50% for 1 minute
      meter_name: cpu_util
      statistic: avg
      period: 60
      evaluation_periods: 1
      threshold: 50
      alarm_actions:
        - {get_attr: [server_scaleup_policy, alarm_url]}
      matching_metadata: {'metadata.user_metadata.stack': {get_param: "OS::stack_id"}}
      comparison_operator: gt

  cpu_alarm_low:
    type: OS::Ceilometer::Alarm
    properties:
      description: Scale-down if the average CPU < 15% for 1 minute
      meter_name: cpu_util
      statistic: avg
      period: 60
      evaluation_periods: 1
      threshold: 15
      alarm_actions:
        - {get_attr: [server_scaledown_policy, alarm_url]}
      matching_metadata: {'metadata.user_metadata.stack': {get_param: "OS::stack_id"}}
      comparison_operator: lt
```

When i would launch this stack, openstack tell the following error:
NotFound: resources.cpu_alarm_low: Not Found (HTTP 404) (Request-ID: req-37d6c753-40db-4596-86a4-e1d10f0c531a)

Under Ressources Type OS::Ceilometer::Alarm is avaible.

Have i forgot to load something in my localrc?
Here a part of my localrc

```
# Enable the Ceilometer devstack plugin
enable_plugin ceilometer https://git.openstack.org/openstack/ceilometer.git

#Ceilometer-services
enable_service ceilometer-acompute ceilometer-acentral ceilometer-anotification ceilometer-collector ceilometer-api

#Ceilometer-alarm
enable_service ceilometer-alarm-notifier ceilometer-alarm-evaluator

#Ceilometer-ipmi (Use only if required)
enable_service ceilometer-aipmi
```

Hope u can help me.

Best Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Recheck the template. Or you may refer to this http://superuser.openstack.org/articles/simple-auto-scaling-environment-with-heat and recheck the syntax, I think you are missing the resource ID, which tells that which resource you want to monitor.